# json4s deserialized object does not match original

Tags: scala, json4s

In Scala 2.10.6, using json4s 3.2.11, to which I'm constrained for now, using the following code:

```
object Thing1 extends Enumeration {
    type Thing1 = Value
    val A = Value(0, "A")
    val B = Value(1, "B")
}

object Thing2 extends Enumeration {
    type Thing2 = Value
    val A = Value(0, "A")
    val B = Value(1, "B")
    val C = Value(2, "C")
}

case class ThingHolder(thing1: Thing1, thing2: Thing2)

class ThingSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
    "desrialized" should "match original" in {
        import org.json4s.native.Serialization.writePretty
        implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + new EnumNameSerializer(Thing1) + new EnumNameSerializer(Thing2)

        val original = ThingHolder(Thing1.A, Thing2.C)
        println(original)

        val serialized = writePretty(original)
        println(serialized)

        val jValue = JsonParser.parse(serialized)
        val deserialized = jValue.camelizeKeys.extract[ThingHolder]
        println(deserialized)
        println(deserialized.thing1)

        deserialized should be(original)
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
ThingHolder(A,C)
{
  "thing1":"A",
  "thing2":"C"
}
ThingHolder(A,C)
A

ThingHolder(A,C) was not equal to ThingHolder(A,C)
```

This occurs with Enumeration, but not another type, for example, String. If the case class has only one Enumeration, it works fine. Why is that? I can correct this by deserializing to a case class with Strings, then mapping to the case class as I want it to be. Is there a way to coax the json4s to deserialize directly such that the deserialized object matches the original?

EDIT:

Here's the hack I mentioned to do the mapping:

```
case class ThingHolderSerialized(thing1: String, thing2: String)
```

...

```
val deserialized = jValue.camelizeKeys.extract[ThingHolderSerialized]
val reconstituted = ThingHolder(Thing1.withName(deserialized.thing1), Thing2.withName(deserialized.thing2))
```

EDIT:

Actually, the separate serializer class is unnecessary:

```
val deserialized = jValue.camelizeKeys.extract[ThingHolder]
val reconstituted = ThingHolder(Thing1.withName(deserialized.thing1.toString), Thing2.withName(deserialized.thing2.toString))
```

EDIT:

It appears that it's thing1 that's not properly deserialized, since this also builds a matching reconstituted object:

```
val reconstituted = deserialized.copy(thing1 = Thing1.withName(deserialized.thing1.toString))
```

but not this:

```
val reconstituted = deserialized.copy(thing2 = Thing2.withName(deserialized.thing2.toString))
```

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is in this case, but in the past to figure out why two objects don't match I usually break my single `should be` statement into a series on statements, one for each field on the object, to see exactly which field does not match.

Comment: @Tyler - in this example, with two enumerations, I'm not sure. But, if ThingHolder has only a Thing1, it will still fail if the second EnumNameSerializer is left in the implicit statement. In that case, there's only one field to fail. That doesn't seem to point to a solution, though.

Comment: @Tyler - it's thing1. See the third EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting this out there as a solution for people that need to support json4s case class deserialization in the presence of multiple Enumerations. It's not the answer I'm looking for, but works in the meantime:

```
object Thing1 extends Enumeration {
    type Thing1 = Value
    val A = Value(0, "A")
    val B = Value(1, "B")
}

object Thing2 extends Enumeration {
    type Thing2 = Value
    val A = Value(0, "A")
    val B = Value(1, "B")
    val C = Value(2, "C")
}

case class ThingHolder(thing1: Thing1, thing2: Thing2)

class ThingSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
    "reconstituted" should "match original" in {
        import org.json4s.native.Serialization.writePretty
        implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + new EnumNameSerializer(Thing1) + new EnumNameSerializer(Thing2)

        val original = ThingHolder(Thing1.A, Thing2.C)
        println(original)

        val serialized = writePretty(original)
        println(serialized)

        val jValue = JsonParser.parse(serialized)
        val deserialized = jValue.camelizeKeys.extract[ThingHolder]
        println(deserialized)

        val reconstituted = deserialized.copy(thing1 = Thing1.withName(deserialized.thing1.toString))
        reconstituted should be(original)
    }
}
```

The key is in the line where we're building `reconstituted`. We make a copy, and in the process, convert thing1 to a string and back to an Enumeration. Fortunately, toString works without the field being correctly deserialized.